# Integrate SonataAdminBundle + FOSUserBundle Without SonataUserBundle for security in symfony 2.3?

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle for authentication and roles. For admin panel I am using SonataAdminBundle.

FOSUserBundle Version 2.0.dev (which support event listeners).

When I tried to install SonataUserBundle, It accept only <= 1.3 version of FOSUserBundle(without event listeners)

I need FOSUserBundle with event listeners.

Does anyone know how to provide security with FOSUserBundle (for Admin & Client panel both)?

Comment: Perhaps you will like to know than their is now an other bundle than replace SonataAdminBundle and works with 2.0 https://github.com/KingCrunch/UserAdminBundle

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

and then type version:

```
dev-master as 1.3.2
```

then you can install Sonata User Bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Should work with inline alias in your `composer.json`

```
 "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev as 1.3.2"
```

Comment: Thanks Pazi, I will check it out